# parse a htmlpage injected as a String ? (String to XML)

Tags: java, xml, nsxmlparser

I got this as a String to my prepareXml method

```
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=4>Detail of your Trip</TD></TR>
<TR></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=4>Booking Ref. : XXX</TD></TR>
<TR></TR>
 <TR>
 <TD>Client</TD>
 <TD colSpan=2>Ticket Number</TD>
 <TD>FOID</TD></TR>
 <TR>
 <TD>Person (ADT)</TD>
 <TD colSpan=2>000000</TD>
<TD>XXXX</TD></TR>
 <TR></TR>
  <TR>
 <TD>From: Location 1</TD>
 <TD>To : Location 2</TD>
 <TD colSpan=2>Flight : LLL</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=2></TD>
<TD colSpan=2>Departure : 14Aug, 15:55 Latest check-in time limit : 15:25 </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=2></TD>
<TD colSpan=2>Arrival : 17:25</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=2></TD>
<TD colSpan=2>Class N</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>From : Location 2</TD>
<TD>To :Location1</TD>
<TD colSpan=2>Flight : AF2585 Resa : OK</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=2></TD>
<TD colSpan=2>Departure : "Time" Latest check-in time limit : "Time" </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=2></TD>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=2></TD>
```

Class N

I have this as a string and i should parse it and send it as an xml

I want to get the Flight number Ticket number  , and departure loc , arrival loc ..And also check whether it is one way or two way ..

How can i do that.. As it is really big what is the best way to parse this ?

Help appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the HTML using e.g., [NekoHTML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nekohtml/). `Neko` is an open source parser/tag balancer which lets you use regular XML operations to traverse and extract information from your document. E.g.,

```
String html = ...
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
parser.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes())));
Document = parser.getDocument(); // standard org.w3c.dom.Document
```

At this stage you *could* also hook it up to a `XPATH` parser such as [Jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/) to extract the desired information more conveniantly.